# Difference in Matplotlib colors using VSCode and Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a matplotlib stylesheet for stylizing my plots and I am noticing a difference between the yellow/orange color when I render the plot using VSCode and Jupyter notebooks. I will need to use both and I need the colors to be consistent. Is there something I am doing wrong? I am not a graphic designer, I just want to be lazy and have all my plots styled the same way, so I don't know much about color rendering.

The yellow is: #FFB700 and the blue is: #003B95.

This plot has the colors I am looking for, and came from VSCode.

[image: Plot of fake data using VSCode]

This came from a Jupyter notebook and the colors are not right.

[image]

Edit: Here is code to reproduce the plot. The first line is the line inside mystylesheet.mplstyle and the rest is the python code.

```
axes.prop_cycle: cycler('color', ['003B95', 'FFB700'])

line_dates = pandas.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=12)
line_data1 = numpy.random.randint(1, 100, 12)
line_data2 = numpy.random.randint(1, 100, 12)

plt.plot(line_dates, line_data1, label='Data 1')
plt.plot(line_dates, line_data2, label='Data 2')
plt.savefig("fake_data_plot.png")
# Using plt.show() has the same color differences
```

Comment: Can you share a plot of toy data with how you are applying the colors? For Jupyter, it looks like you are getting the defaults perhaps. The different package combinations can have different defaults.

Comment: I added the code to reproduce the plot in my OP.

Comment: I think that the addition is an improvement and someone may be able to determine what is going on with that alone; however, I am not able to reproduce this with that alone. Maybe a different tack would be to make a gist and share all the code for a toy example with the style sheet, too. ( I don't have a good gist example to show you. I have some plot code [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/bb5a9c727d93d1508187677b4d74d7c1) and the notebook renders nicely [here on nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/bb5a9c727d93d1508187677b4d74d7c1).  ...

Comment: <continued>  (You don't need to do it in a notebook even, just the code would be a good step.) And full repo with all code [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder) to give you an idea of what I mean.) See the section of  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where it says 'Help others reproduce the problem'.

Comment: I figured it out from your first comment. I specified the dpi=300 and that worked. Somehow reminding me about the defaults jogged my memory. Sorry about the incomplete code. I will put together a repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try #FFC32D colour for yellow. If it won't be good use some app like "Color Grab" to check the right colour.

Comment: Thanks for the color suggestion! If I change the color in the stylesheet, won't that change the color in VSCode plots too? I was hoping to be able to sync the colors a little better.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).